# Cast exception in generic type

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class clsA<T, T1>
    where T : class
    where T1 : class
{
    public T GetEntity()
    {
        return (T) new clsB<T1>();            
    }
}
```

> I am getting error **Cannot convert type `clsB<T1>` to T**

Please help

Comment: What language is this? Can you please add a language tag to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `T` could be anything -- `string` for example, and that would cause the cast to fail.  If `T` cannot be a variable type, then do not include it in the generic argument list.

If you want to allow `T` to be `clsB<T1>` or any subtype, and you want to construct an instance of that class, then do this instead:

```
public class clsA<T, T1>
    where T : clsB<T1>, new()
    where T1 : class
{
    public T GetEntity()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Then, given the type:

```
public class clsC : clsB<string> { }
```

Invoking `GetEntity()` on an object of type `clsA<clsC, string>` will construct and return an instance of `clsC`.